# Connecting to SQL from Excel VBA: VBA error message= 'Not able to find ISAM file'

Tags: vba, ms-access, powerquery

When setting and running ADODB connection to SQL from Excel VBA, I get an error message:

> Not able to find the ISAM file

I wrote the following connection in a VBA module:

```
    "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
    "Data Source=" & PWRQRYFilePath
```

Im using Excel 2019, 32 bits.
Referencing to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.

How do I create and open the connection?

I'm trying to create and open the connection so I can run SQL queries from Excel VBA.

Following is a simple query to obtain a join inner from two spreadsheets. It is sending me the error message.

Comment: There is no "connection to SQL" - SQL is not a db, it is a language. You want Access VBA to open a recordset of data from Excel? If not using Access VBA nor Access data, then why the ms-access tag? There is no "following" query in your narrative. What is the value of `PWRQRYFilePath`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of the variable **PWRQRYFilePath**?

For the sake of completeness:

If you want to go the long way, or better spoken, if you need the query more times, as you know, you can put the code lines also in a function an pass the path to the file to it.... here its represented by the Workbook-Property ThisWorkbook.Fullname

```
Dim rs As Object 'or AS ADODB.Recordset for EarlyBinding/IntelliSense

With rs
    .Open "SELECT * FROM [worksheetname$] WHERE [column]='value'", _
        ";Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0" & _
        ";Extended Properties""Excel 12.0 xml""" & _
        ";Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
        '*** do your stuff with recordsetresult
    
    .Close
End With
```

If you need the query just once, you can use a anonym function call as well:

```
With CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   .OPEN ...
   '*** do your stuff ...
   .CLOSE
End With
```